# Map<String, ? super Number> for adding and Map<String, ? extends Number> for printing is producing errors

Tags: java, generics

I have read through several posts on here about this topics.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/1068249) was a especially a good post

I thought I understood the **PECS**-concept, and tried to set up a small example to test it out.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, ? super Number> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("int", 1);
        map.put("double", 1.0);
        map.put("long", 100000000000L);

        print(map);

    }

    public static void print(Map<String, ? extends Number> map) {
        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("Key: %s, Val: %s%n", k, v));
    }
}
```

I know I need to use `super` to be able to insert multiple subtypes in to the same map.

But when it comes to printing. I thought using `extends` would be sufficient, since **PE**CS (Producer extends)

Instead I get this:

```
Error:(12, 15) java: incompatible types: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,capture#1 of ? super java.lang.Number> cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,? extends java.lang.Number>
```

Comment: There's​ no problem with the `print()` method; the problem is what you're trying to pass into it. What if `map` is `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: You map is both a producer, and a consumer of Number, so its generic type must both extend Number, and super Number. There is only one type that can do that: Number. So it should be a Map<String, Number>.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's usually a bad idea to instantiate a collection with a wildcard type. You'll almost always want to read from *and* write to said collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases `Number` suffices and is most adequate.

As said `super` does not make sense; you could just as well have written Object.

```
Map<String, Number> map = new HashMap<>();
```

With this you may put a Number or a child of Number into the map.
Or get a Number or a parent of Number from the map.

Now if you would use:

```
public static void print(Map<String, ? extends Number> map) {
```

you cannot put a `Double` (or whatever) into that `map` as the actual map argument could have been a `Map<String, Integer>`. Hence `Map<String, Number>`.

As the type system of java is not very strong/expressive, a good rule is to keep `extends` for meta level constructs (=when you need them). For simple data structures **PECS** follows from the data flow.

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
    Map<String, ? super Number> map
```

may contain any values, try this

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("1", "2");
Map<String, ? super Number> map = map1;
```

there is no compile error